# Text field для перехода в другой View controller

Tags: xcode, ios

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть проект в Xcode. В нем есть View controller, на котором расположен text field. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при вводе определенного слова открывался другой View controller. Каким образом это сделать?

Спасибо.

Comment: А как же Матчасть?? Гугел??? Читайте, разбирайтесь, а не вы по простейшему вопросу создаете quest. Тогда чему нибудь и научитесь, имхо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод UITextFieldDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Просматриваете, что вводится, и делаете переход на новый view controller способом, который вам нравится.

Comment: Я вообще думал так сделать:

    - (IBAction)textFieldDidEndOnExit:(UITextField *)sender
{
[sender resignFirstResponder];
if ([sender.text isEqualToString:@"open2"])
{

}
}

Но вот не знаю что написать во вторых фигурных скобках.
Или так нельзя сделать?

Comment: @Ruslan_T, так зачем вам екшен? Вы же сами написали, что "Нужно сделать так, чтобы при вводе определенного слова...". Если вы хотите переход по кнопке, тогда еще проще. 

    if ([self.textField.text isEqualToString:@"open2"])
    {
        TwoVK *twoVK = [[TwoVK alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:twoVK animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

Comment: Почему-то при запуске приложения с таким кодом после ввода фразы open2 появляется черный экран, что могло пойти не так?